# Install app via usb: The device is temporarily restricted

Tags: android, adb, development-environment, miui

When I toggle on the *install via USB* in developer mode:

- it will pop the toast message said that *the device is temporarily restricted*
- then toggle off the settings.

Is there any solution for this?
I searched through all the way like turning off MIUI optimization but still does not work. I cannot debug my application by Android Studio in this way......

Comment: You have developer account? MIUI devices binded to it's accounts.

Comment: Do u mean Mi account? Or I have to sign a developer account beside than Mi account. Last month I can use normally, but this month suddenly like this

Comment: I not very familiar with MIUI, but other peoples with MIUI  tells me, what they must get special permission as "developer account". Sorry, I don't know more details.

Comment: Nvm, thank for your suggestions. I think this is MIUI bug but I not sure, because people complain last year and still no any official reply.

Comment: I got this problem in my Xiaomi Mi5 from India. All the mentioned solutions didn't work in my case. Then I tried to figure out the Core reason behind it and solve it. In MIUI, in order to change "Install via USB" option, you must be connected to the internet and signed in your Mi account. Due to some reason, requests from out of the China servers are getting rejected, so I connected to one open China VPN and tried again to enable 'Install via USB' and I got success. For detailed solution and VPN details, see this useful Youtube video: https://youtu.be/MeKUJlD-Ke4

Comment: Possibly related on Android.SE: [Enable "Install via USB" without creating MI Account](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185116/44325)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For me on a rooted **MIUI v.8.5.1** I just need to:

- turn off wifi
- turn on mobile connection In development options

after doing that both *Install via USB* and *USB debugging* started to work.

Comment: that method doesnt work anymore. You have to use china VPN

Comment: How to make it work in MIUI 9? does not work with it.

Comment: if somebody still get problem to enable "Install via USB", then try Security App -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On "Install via USB"

Comment: Works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 96):

**"Install via USB"** wont work if your Xiaomi phone is running **MIUI 8 or above**. Looks like when you try to Enable this option, your phone trys to connect to some chinese server and fails.

I got a work around and it worked for me. Idea is to connect to Chinese-Shanghai server through VPN. Try the following:

1. Install **PlexVPN** from Playstore and login into it. You will get a 24 hr free VPN service.
2. Select **China-Shanghai** server and connect.
3. From developer option in your Xiaomi phone, **Enable "Install via USB"**.
4. You can then disconnect the VPN and logout from PlexVPN.

Enjoy!!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Many many thanks

Comment: Yep, it works! I'm from Spain and have Orange and it's the only solution so far. Thank you.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. It works great.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Such a weird thing. Dont know how but it works. Thank you

Comment: This is the only solution that works for newer MIUI versions, I tried everything else. Thanks!

Comment: can't wait until there is a lineage os version for the note 5a

Comment: Worked. In my case cannot connect with China-Shangai server (but the "Free Connection" worked for me)
@kyo You should select this as the correct answer.

Comment: I use Transocks chinese app, much simpler and it's free~

Comment: If you dont get it for free, try this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47870600/7710739

Comment: VPN works flawlessly! Had to use my SIM card nevertheless... Now "they" got my phone number

Comment: this app no longer have shanghai. I use "China VPN" with beijing server as alternative and it works. Also notes that I use mobile data (redmi 7) https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fix-the-device-is-temporarily-restricted-3-3-unlock-usb-debugging.4358067/

Answer (score 52):

All you have to do is Turn your Wi-Fi off, turn on mobile data, and then enable the setting for "Install via USB". It'll go through.

Source: http://en.miui.com/thread-544718-1-1.html

Comment: yeah, but when I am trying to do this - device is asking for interner connection. how do I deal with it ?

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Sorry, I left my answer incomplete. I've edited it now. You also need to turn on mobile data.

Comment: This actually works. My device is Xiaomi Redmi Note 4. Note that I switched off the MIUI optimization too (from dharmx's answer), though.

Comment: Apart from this, in developer options go for last item name is 'Turn on MIUI optimization', turn off this option it will ask for reboot , then reboot device by clicking Turn off & reboot button

Comment: Try my solution.

Comment: Doesn't work, it says "Connect to the network and try again" :(

Comment: You need to be connected to the Internet via mobile data.

Comment: thanks, finally found this answer. worked for me without turning off MIUI optimization in xiaomi redmi note 4.

Answer (score 24):

Try this

1. Settings ->  Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn off Miui Optimizations -> Restart
2. Security -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On "Install via USB"
3. Settings ->  Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On/Off "USB Debugging" -> Turn On "Install vis USB"

Comment: Restarting after turning off miui Optimizations worked for me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, at least for MIUI v8.5.5.0, The crappiest operating system ever, don't ever buy a phone that ships this malware

Comment: Remember to turn OFF then turn ON for USB Debugging option, after you restart before turning on Install via USB.

Comment: I also think this should be accepted answer. For me only two steps was enough to be able to install app from Android Studio (I don't need to enable option in developer options - it is turned off and I am able to install :))

Comment: i wasnt able to turn ON install via usb, but probably turning off miui optimization helped (also restarted), i am able to run app from android studio now - while install via usb is off and still asks for sim card.. also none of the vpn fixes worked for me.

Comment: this Miui optimisation options is missing now

Comment: Turn off Miui Optimizations worked for me with a restart

Answer (score 20):

Turning off Wi-Fi and enabling Mobile Data (*thank you Xiaomi for wasting my money to enabling mobile data which the last one I didn't have*) on Xiaomi 4A did not work for me. Every time I tried to enable `Install App Via USB` it displayed me "**the device is temporarily restricted**". So, I found this solution:

Turn on VPN onto your device with these parameters and try again toggle `Install from USB`:

- Server Address: `China server from https://www.vpngate.net/en/`
- IPSec Key: `vpn`
- Username: `vpn`
- Password: `vpn`

[image: I hope this info will be helpful to someone]

Comment: this one was the only one that worked for me (Xiaomi Remdi 4x, MiUI 9.1

Comment: Use this site to get vpn username and password, connecting to a china server worked for us https://www.vpngate.net/en/

Comment: I used a server located in Hong Kong. China server did not work for me.

Comment: yeah, we can use vpn to enable it again :) good luck!

Answer (score 13):

(1) **Turn Off** your **Wi-Fi**
(2) **Turn On** your **Mobile Data**
(3) **Turn On "Install via USB"** from Developer Option of your device.
That's all

Answer (score 9):

i had same problem with MI Redmi 4a i solved it by ->

first become a developer by clicking on

**setting->About phone->MIUI version** (7-8 times)

then, **setting->additional setting->developer options->USB debugging**

Turn on your usb debugging, then in **developer options** go for last item name is '**Turn on MIUI optimization**', turn off this option it will ask for reboot , then reboot device by clicking Turn off & reboot button

after reboot go to **Setting->Permissions** click on top right menu button Turn on **install via USB** option

thats it !

Comment: I actually try this, but it still doesn't work for my device. Btw, now it is okay even though i dunno what happen, the option suddenly working perfectly without any updates or setting change.... I wonder what MIUI working...

Comment: you can also use it over wifi if you have.

Comment: Works like a Charm !! Thanks

Comment: **NOTE** if "Permissions" not listed then search it in Settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The Best what I found devices without mobile data in device is to **SIGN_OUT from MI_Account** in the device and Login Again -> Try to **enable USB_Debugging(Security Setting)**-> enable **INSTALL_VIA_USB**

Comment: Thank you very much.This trick work for me,to wresting more time after.

Comment: this is the only solution that works for me. redmi 5A, miui 9.1.8

Answer (score 6):

**These steps worked for me after struggling 1 hour, Not needed to connect to Chinese server.**
(1) Turn Off your Wi-Fi 
(2) Turn Off your Mobile Data 
(3) Turn On "Install via USB" from Developer Option of your device. 
4) It will show the Error "No network found"  
5) Now Turn On your Mobile Data 
6) Again Turn on "Install via USB" 
7) it will work, now
Happy!

Comment: when i turn off mobile data and click "Install vis USB" it pops up to sign into MI UI Account.

Answer (score 5):

In MIUI 8.5 it gives the error like you mention while enabling "install via USB", to resolve the error you need to make WIFI off and make mobile data on and then enable the option “Install via USB”. it will work for you.

A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/xiaomi-mi-note-4-install-via-usb-device-temporarily-restricted/

Answer (score 5):

You will need to sign up/sign in for a Mi account before you continue.

1) Extract sim card from your non-Redmi phone. (It should be nano sim. Contact your telecom provider to get one if you have a micro or normal sim).

2) Insert sim card into Redmi phone.

3) Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options.

4) Under Debugging, click on 'Install via USB' option.

The phone will enable this.

Remove the sim card.

That's it!! You should now be able to install your apps via USB from Android studio.

Please remember not to disable this option, otherwise, you may need to re-insert your sim card.

PLEASE NOTE: The above steps are guaranteed to work in Xiaomi Redmi 5 phone. Please improve this answer if the steps are different for other models of Xiaomi.

Answer (score 4):

Disable WiFi and switch install via USB on while you are connected through data and under your xiaomi account. It works!

Comment: Not working connect to the network and try again display

Comment: @GaneshGiri Tun on Mobile data and tun off WiFi and try again

Answer (score 4):

In my case,

I `turned on Airplane mode` and

`turn it off` then

`turn off Wifi` and

`turn on mobile data`.

Now I can turn on install via USB.

May it helps some one like me.

Answer (score 3):

Please **verify** your email and phone number in Mi account first then try this:

1. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn off Miui Optimizations -> Restart
2. Security -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On "Install via USB"
3. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On/Off "USB Debugging" -> Turn On "Install vis USB"

Comment: After turning off MiUi optimizations I was able to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

Redmi Note 4 (Nougat 7.0, MIUI 9)

For me, options like *Turning WiFi off & on*, trying on *Data Network*, or *Turning off MIUI Optimization* din't work.
Also, the `Install via USB` never got enabled.

Following steps helped me to install apps via USB

- `Additional Settings` > `Developer Options`
- Here, click on `USB Debugging (Security Settings)`. This will take you through some warning screens. Allow (click on Next/Accept) for all. At the end, it will be enabled.
- Now turn on the `Install via USB` and it gets enabled.
- Try to Run the app by connecting your device. If it still doesn't run (as in my case), find `Select USB Configuration` and select `Charging`
  This worked for me.

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

Solution with NO VPNing that worked for me:

1. go to `Settings->Accounts->MiAccount->AccountSecurity->Devices`
2. I had a Redmi 9 device listed there (I don't own a Redmi device)
3. I removed that Device, so now no devices were listed
4. go back to developer settings, enable install via USB, everything works.

I assume not everyone will have a Redmi device listed there, maybe some will have a different device, maybe some will even have the correct device(this is not something I can test by myself), but it makes sense to me that correcting any wrong devices from that list (or maybe deleting all devices like I did) might fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem in my Xiaomi Mi5 from India. All the mentioned solutions didn't work in my case. Then I tried to figure out the Core reason behind it and solve it. In MIUI, in order to change "Install via USB" option, you must be connected to the internet and signed in your Mi account. Due to some reason, requests from out of the China servers are getting rejected, so I connected to one open China VPN and tried again to enable 'Install via USB' and I got success. For detailed solution and VPN details, see this useful Youtube video: https://youtu.be/MeKUJlD-Ke4

Comment: Your most welcome Som. Glad it worked. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

I will write what worked for me, these other solutions did not work out.

switch "Install via USB" to ON,

When the dialog box "Allowing" appear, quick tap your screen out of the dialog box.

Repeat it until u see that "Install via USB" is ON.

After u see "Install Via USB" is ON, you need to re-checking by pressing back button and go to developer option again.

This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on my Redmi Note 4 with MIUI 9. For me the procedure is very simple.

**1. Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Gear icon at top right corner.**

**2. Give the required permission for Install via USB.**

**3. Goto  Developer Options and try using Install via USB. It will work now.**

This process is for one time. I hope you have resolved this issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem with **Xiaomi Mi5 MUI9**.

Turning on/off connections or MUI optimization did not work for me.
What worked is:

> **Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy -> enable Unknown sources**

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i updated MIUI version to the new available version, resolved the issue.
So check if there is any update available for your device, go to

> Settings => About phone => System update
>   => here it will shows you the new available MIUI version for your device. So update it then try again.

Note: Turn your Mobile data before enabling install via USB.

Comment: After updating the OS, i have regstered my mobile number +91 ... which created account and then enabled the USB debugging

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I connect to Chinese VPN, then I turn on install via USB and its work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, tried all the suggested workarounds, but none of them worked for me. Strangely enough, what actually has worked for me was **turning on MIUI optimization** (it was turned off when the problem occurred)! After turning it on, I was able to toggle on *install via USB*.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to **settings**-> **Mi Account**->**Account security**
Then verify phone and email, If not added then add and verify that

Comment: Its same after getting verified

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to no result, then read somewhere that you should use VPN and connect under China to unlock your phone's bootloader. Applied the same solution here and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If turning your Wi-Fi off is not working for you, then you might have not yet registered your MIUI account as a developer account.

To do so go to  [MIUI Dev center](https://dev.mi.com/) and register your already created account. After the review process this should not be bugging you anymore.

But remember as other have noted to:

- Turn off Wi-Fi connection
- Turn on mobile connection

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I was using my phone that is Redmi 4 and the usb debugging was not working.It was always giving the message **"the device is temporarily restricted"** .I have tried all this steps but the result was same.Then I found the foolish thing that I have put the device in charging mode only.When I switch to **MTP(Transfer files)** and then it started working correctly.I know its a foolish thing but it may help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

if you have root you can force it with adb shell

`adb shell
su
setprop persist.security.adbinput 1`

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions doesn't work for me. In my case it works by changing Additional settings -> Region to Russia/Some other country.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Redmi 3s prime with MIUI 9.2, enabling MIUI optimisation on developer menu worked. It caused phone to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on **MIUI Global 9.6 | Stable [9.6.1.0 (NCFMIFD)]**.

Problem for me was that wifi was not connected. As mentioned in some answers, apparently device tries to connect to server.

It works for without mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every method mentioned here but unfortunately none were worked for MI 5A . 
Finally i have succeeded by connected to open china VPN

settings->VPN->add new VPN->
Name:Give some name ,
Type:L2TP/IPSec PSK ,
Server address: vpn601519347.opengw.net ,
IPSec preshared key :vpn ,
User name :vpn ,
Password :vpn .

Press OK, Enable VPN
once the connection is successful
go to developer option and enable install via USB option.

You can also try different server address like 
china088.opengw.net , 
vpn959922015.opengw.net

Answer (score 0):

For anyone want to use free option you can install `1.1.1.1: Faster & Safer Internet` before turn on `Install via USB`

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to disable MIUI optimization as suggested by other users
All you got to do is head over to Developer options and tap on “Reset to default values” a few times. And the miui optimization will appear

Answer (score -5):

Wifi has to be off for security reasons because you can use adb over wifi