# Install Via USB not working - on 7.0 device

Tags: android-usb, redmi-device, miui, xiaomi, redmi-permission

I have red mi note 4 devices after update device with miui version 9 attempt to enable installation via application via USB, it doesn't work and shows "This device is temporarily restricted". The solution I found didn't work.
Without that feature, I can't develop an application.
Model redmi note 4
miui version: 9.0.5.0[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install app via usb: The device is temporarily restricted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020237/install-app-via-usb-the-device-is-temporarily-restricted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I was not able to enable Install Via USB option, however, I found a solution that actually worked.

Here are the steps to enable it.

1. Install [PlexVPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoplex.plex&hl=en) app on your mobile phone
2. Open PlexVPN then set VPN to China (e.g **China-Shanghai**) and connect
3. Go to Developer Options and enable **Install Via USB** option
4. Enjoy :)

Comment: If you don't want to install any 3rd party app, then go for this solution: Due to some reason, requests from out of the China servers are getting rejected, so I connected to one open China VPN and tried again to enable 'Install via USB' and I got success. For detailed solution and VPN details, see this useful Youtube video: [https://youtu.be/MeKUJlD-Ke4][1]


  [1]: https://youtu.be/MeKUJlD-Ke4

Comment: PlexVPN is paid for china-shanghai 
@Perry sadly first link is not used anymore, second link vpn connection goes unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only solution that worked is to toggle on **OEM unlocking**

Only then I could enable **Install via USB** and other options that previously restricted

Answer (score 1):

yes the solution is VPN you need chinese serevr  for proxy , should is buy vpn or i can do it for free , follow the links below
i faced the problem before so [here is answer](https://medium.com/@rizwanchouhan/this-device-is-temporarily-restricted-3-3-xiomi-mobile-install-app-via-usb-free-solution-3c7153cb265a)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21336094)

Comment: i have edited my answer . solution is vpn need chinese server . thanks for the  review , i will keep this in my mind in the future. please dont vote me down i am already low. and  i was trying to help nothing else