# Red mi device issue on enable "Installl via usb"

Tags: android, usb, android-debug, redmi-device, redmi-permission

I am using the mi note 5a device with MiUI 9. but when I enable the option of Install by USB developer option its show error. can anyone help me how to fix that I was using some process that below

1. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn off Miui Optimizations -> Restart

2.Security -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On “Install via USB”

3. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On/Off “USB Debugging” -> Turn On “Install vis USB”

None of them is useful in my issue

[image]

Comment: that Ans is not working for my problem and my issue is showing               " The device is temporarily restricted, 3-2"

Comment: could you tell me your MIUI version

Comment: First see that you have miui account activated then follow the below link i think its just a temporary solution but you can try it if not working then reply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735264/9287163

Comment: hi, I am using that but not working now I have show different message " The device is temporarily restricted, 3-1". I have more than 5 devices with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- Turn off WIFI and Turn on mobile data..
- Then go to setting --> additional settings --> developer options and turn off MIUI Optimization
- After that go to security --> permission --> setting icon on top right corner and turn on install via usb.
- After that go to setting --> additional settings --> developer options --> turn on usb debugging --> turn on install via usb

Comment: this all condition is true but not working yet show error

Comment: This did the job for me - Then go to setting --> additional settings --> developer options and turn off MIUI Optimization

Answer (score 0):

try this :

- Disable WiFi
- Enable Data Connnection
- Enable “Installl via usb”

Answer (score 0):

First Check in your computer USB driver is installed or not.
If not than install ADB driver.