# Is there any solution of "java.io.IOException" problem in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ioexception

Recently I have moved to windows 10, reinstalled JDK, android studio and all device drivers now I am facing this **"java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
Error while Installing APK"** problem which is blocking me running the generated apk to a real device. What should I do to get rid of it?

Here is a screenshot of the problem

[Android studio "java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
Error while Installing APK" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2lF3.png)

I have already tried

1. Restarting android studio
2. Invalidating cache and restart android studio.
3. Killing adb.exe and restart android studio

Comment: if your app was previously installed in your mobile device, try uninstalling the app first. when you re-install the IDE, it creates a new SHA key for your debug app. this may prevent the IDE from deleting the old copy of your app and re-installing with the latest one during installation.

Comment: Thank you very much but no app is installed in my mobile device

Comment: you might want to google for the model of your device (some devices have extra settings for you to tweak before you can install apps on it). e.g. is Mi phones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020237/install-app-via-usb-the-device-is-temporarily-restricted. the problem can be due to the device, and not the IDE. try testing with another phone if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try killing and restarting adb server by `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`.

Failing that might a restart of your machine could do the trick and or checking for any updates too Android Studio.